# Residue Calculation Question

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a function such as $e(2z)/cos(z)$ for example and then I know that there are an infinite number of poles which occur when cos(z)=0. How would I go about calculating the residues for each of these poles as a general expression?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple pole at $\;\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb Z$, and the residue there is

$$\lim_{z\to\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2}\left(z-\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2\right)\frac{e^{2z}}{\cos z}=\frac{e^{(2n-1)\pi}}{\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2}=\begin{cases}\;\;\;e^{(2n-1)\pi}&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\-e^{(2n-1)\pi}&,\;\;n\;\;\text{is even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Okay, I tried calculating it myself and I got that the coefficient is negative when n is odd and when positive when n is even. I calculated the residue by differentiating the denominator and plugging in the pole to e^(2n-1)*pi / -sin((2n-1)*pi/2)

Comment: @user153009 Remember that $$\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}2=1\iff n\;\;\text{is odd}$$